# Registering Workflow Manager fails because the farm is already registered

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I have a standalone SharePoint server 2013 (Win2008r2) for test purposes. I have installed Workflow Manager, marking "`Allow Http`" in the wizard. The certificates were auto-generated.
The server does not have AD.

Now I am trying to run `Register-SPWorkflowService` and receive the following error:
[image]

Workflow service status shows that it is not connected:
[image]

The port seems correct:
[image]

1. I have created new application and new site collection-> the same issue
2. I ran the cmdlet with -Force, it executed without errors but the Workflow Service status did not change.

Comment: It's also helpful [Register-SPWorkflowService: Failed to register because the farm is already registered with a workflow service.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/reregister-sharepoint-workflow-manager-service/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, what I did:

- Go to Central Admin > Application management > Manager services Application > Click on Workflow Service Application Proxy. then from Ribbon Delete it.
- re-run the register workflow Command. using the -force parameter